# How to close SSH socket

Tags: bash, ssh, xargs

I'm working on enabling  Session Multiplexing between two servers.
I want to close all existing sockets for this server(or IP) before creating new one and close newly created one after finishing my task. This is what I've done so far:

```
    remote_ip=192.168.20.2      #User inut
    remote_port=222
```

Can create socket by:

```
    SSHSOCKET=~/.ssh/remote_$remote_ip
    ssh -M -f -N -o ControlPath=$SSHSOCKET $remote_ip -p $remote_port
```

Can search control path by:

```
ps x | grep $remote_ip | grep ssh | cut -d '=' -f 2
      /root/.ssh/remote_192.168.20.2 192.168.20.2 -p 222
```

Can close socket by:

```
ssh -S /root/.ssh/remote_192.168.20.2 192.168.20.2 -p 64555 -O exit
```

Trying to close the socket by:

```
ps x | grep $remote_ip | grep ssh | cut -d '=' -f 2 | xargs ssh -S | xargs -i {} "-O exit"
```

But I get:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
```

Tried using -t and -tt:

```
        ps x | grep $remote_ip | grep ssh | cut -d '=' -f 2 | xargs ssh -Stt | xargs -i {} "-O exit"
        ssh: Could not resolve hostname /root/.ssh/remote_192.168.20.2: Name or service not known
        xargs: ssh: exited with status 255; aborting
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Why do you *need* a ptty allocated? That's a warning, not an error. Is there a reason you aren't just ignoring it?

Comment: though `xargs -i {} "-O exit"` has its own problems, unrelated to PTY allocation.

Comment: ...frankly, why are you grepping `ps` at all? You can get the socket straight off the filesystem.

Comment: `ssh -S /root/.ssh/remote_192.168.20.2 192.168.20.2 -p 64555 -O exit` which closes the socket causing no error/warning.
but `ps x | grep $remote_ip | grep ssh | cut -d '=' -f 2 | xargs ssh -S | xargs -i {} "-O exit"` does not although this interprets exactly like above.

Comment: Yes, I can remove from file system but I wouldn't know if there any socket exists(created by other users) or where it's stored. That's why I'm searching from `ps`
 I'm sure there are better approaches but so far this is best I could think of.

Comment: no, piping your `xargs` commands to each other is not *at all* identical to your original `ssh` command.

Comment: And I'm not telling you to do a `rm` from the filesystem. Keep in mind that there are facilities like `lsof` to search for open files, or `fuser` to, given a file, identify if any processes are using it.

Comment: `fuser -k -n tcp`
Thanks for the help but "kill all connections across all users" I'm afraid I can't do that. I must not interrupt other users. Here's the scenario: Connections can be opened by other users to different server(IP) and socket file's name/location might vary. So I have to find if there are any existing socket(s) for the server(IP) I working with and stop/remove it.

Comment: Huh? I thought you said that handling sockets created by other users was why you wanted to use `ps` (as opposed to just looking at your current user's `~/.ssh`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154832/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-derp).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to kill every connection from your machine to a given remote IP address and port, you can do so as follows (using `fuser`, a tool from the [psmisc](https://gitlab.com/psmisc/psmisc) package included with all major Linux distros):

```
fuser -k -n tcp ",${remote_ip},${remote_port}"
```